# Textfield in getting refreshed once unfocus

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 4 text fields. If I input new values and unfocus on the 4th field the new values are getting retained as per my expectation.

Then I added 2 more fields (I have replicated the 4th field and made some minor modifications). Now, when I tried to input new values on 1st to 6th fields, then when I unfocus on 6th field, 1st and 2nd gets refreshed to their default value.

I just want to note also that the 6th field when I am typing in it, I cannot see the 1st and 2nd field. I just saw the the 1st and 2nd field are refreshed once I unfocus the 6th field and move the page up.

Please help as to why this is occurring. Thanks!

```
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 20.0,
      vertical: 20.0,
    ),
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Do you want to provide any discount above a minimum cart total amount? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Minimum Amount:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    discountAmt = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    discountAmt = '0';
                  }
                  discountAmt = int.parse(discountAmt).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.discountAmt,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 499',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Text(
        'Input the discount percent? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Discount Percent:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    discountPer = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    discountPer = '0';
                  }
                  discountPer = int.parse(discountPer).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.discountPer,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 10',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Text(
        'Do you want to charge any shipping amount? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Shipping Charge:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    shippingAmt = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    shippingAmt = '0';
                  }
                  shippingAmt = int.parse(shippingAmt).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.shippingAmt,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 50',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Text(
        'Do you want to charge any tax? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Tax Percent:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    taxPer = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    taxPer = '0';
                  }
                  taxPer = int.parse(taxPer).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.taxPer,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 12',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),

      //Added 5th field
      Text(
        'Products that are low on stock will be shown in Inventory tab',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Low Inventory:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    zlowInventory = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    zlowInventory = '0';
                  }
                  zlowInventory = int.parse(zlowInventory).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.zlowInventory,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 50',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),

      //Added 6th field
      Text(
        'Products sold above this will be set as trending products in Products tab',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 14.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          letterSpacing: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Trending Value:  ',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) {
                  if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                    ztrendingVal = val.trim();
                  } else {
                    ztrendingVal = '0';
                  }
                  ztrendingVal = int.parse(ztrendingVal).toString();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                initialValue: cartInfo.ztrendingVal,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'eg: 50',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),

      Container(
        height: 45.0,
        width: size.width,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //update
            updateCartInfo();
          },
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Update Cart Settings',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              letterSpacing: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Add ```TextEditingController``` for your inputs and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this event is that list view renders only those widgets which are in view therefore when you are viewing 6th field then 1 and 2 goes out of view and when you scroll back then they are again rendered thus loosing value. You can solve it by using the SingleChildScrollView.

```
return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 20.0,
      vertical: 20.0,
    ),
      child: Column(
          children:[
            Text(
              'Do you want to provide any discount above a minimum cart total amount? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Minimum Amount:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          discountAmt = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          discountAmt = '0';
                        }
                        discountAmt = int.parse(discountAmt).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.discountAmt,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 499',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Input the discount percent? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Discount Percent:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          discountPer = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          discountPer = '0';
                        }
                        discountPer = int.parse(discountPer).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true,
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.discountPer,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 10',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Do you want to charge any shipping amount? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Shipping Charge:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          shippingAmt = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          shippingAmt = '0';
                        }
                        shippingAmt = int.parse(shippingAmt).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true,
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.shippingAmt,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 50',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Do you want to charge any tax? \n(If left blank then \"0\" will be considered)',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Tax Percent:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          taxPer = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          taxPer = '0';
                        }
                        taxPer = int.parse(taxPer).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true,
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.taxPer,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 12',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),

            //Added 5th field
            Text(
              'Products that are low on stock will be shown in Inventory tab',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Low Inventory:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          zlowInventory = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          zlowInventory = '0';
                        }
                        zlowInventory = int.parse(zlowInventory).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true,
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.zlowInventory,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 50',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),

            //Added 6th field
            Text(
              'Products sold above this will be set as trending products in Products tab',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Trending Value:  ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        if (val.trim().length > 0) {
                          ztrendingVal = val.trim();
                        } else {
                          ztrendingVal = '0';
                        }
                        ztrendingVal = int.parse(ztrendingVal).toString();
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true,
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      initialValue: cartInfo.ztrendingVal,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'eg: 50',
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),

            Container(
              height: 45.0,
              width: size.width,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //update
                  updateCartInfo();
                },
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Update Cart Settings',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
          ]
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. But I feel like it is somehow connected as it only happens when I don't see the field.

here's what I did but somehow I'm getting error

`return Form(
  key: _formKey,
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children:[
          child: ListView(...),
        ]
      ),
    ),
  );`

Comment: Hi @Deepak Lohmod I'm sorry I'm unable to format it correctly. BUt the error I'm having now is: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Comment: @Mr.Tacio Delete the ```ListView```, the proposed solution is using ```Column``` instead

Comment: I have updated my code so you can get it easily. If you found my answer useful then accept it so others can get to know the answer for your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks to both of you. It is now working. I will also take note on this info as this is my first time encountering this behaviour. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't understand, somehow when I have implemented the SingleChildScrollView the text on 3rd and 7th Text becomes indented. It attributes are the same as others. Is there anything else that I might be missing?